# How to read nested array elements from JSON?

Tags: json, jq, nested-lists, jsonpath

I need to parse a JSON with nested array elements and extract the values.

I am not sure how to use the nested array to set the value of an attribute in output JSON.

This is the input:

```
  [{
        "name": "book1",
        "id": 18789,
        "locations": [{
            "state": "mystate",
            "phone": 8877887700
        }, {
            "state": "mystate1",
            "phone": 8877887701
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "book2",
        "id": 18781,
        "locations": [{
            "state": "mystate3",
            "phone": 8877887711
        }, {
            "state": "mystate4",
            "phone": 8877887702
        }]
    }]
```

And this is the expected output:

```
{
    "name": ["book1", "book2"],
    "id": ["18789", "18781"],
    "states": [
        ["mystate", "mystate"],
        ["mystate3", "mystate4"]
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use the following JSLT expression:

```
{
  "name" : [for (.)
               let s = string(.name)
               $s],
"id": [for (.)
               let s = string(.id)
               $s],
"states": [for (.)
               let s = string(.locations)
               $s]
}
```

But I am not sure how to set the `states` in this case so that I have the value of state in the output.

A solution using JQ or JSONPath may also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JQ it'd be easier than that.

```
{
  name:   map(.name),
  id:     map(.id),
  states: map(.locations | map(.state))
}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/acWzuH6TRu)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In JSLT you can implement it like this:

```
{
  "name" : [for (.) .name],
  "id": [for (.) .id],
  "states": flatten([for (.) [for (.locations) .state]])
}
```

The `states` key is a bit awkward to implement, as you see. I have thought of making it possible to let path expressions traverse arrays, and if we add that to the language it could be implemented like this:

```
{
  "name" : .[].name,
  "id": .[].id,
  "states": .[].locations.[].state
}
```